# Passing parameters to a service that already has dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a service with the following constructor

```
public TokenService(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}
```

In Startup.cs I have registered the service :

```
services.AddScoped<TokenService>();
```

I would like to add a string parameter to the constructor and pass the string to the service where I register the service in Startup.cs

I know you can pass parameters by creating a new instance during registration but I don't know how to pass the UserManger and ApplicationDbContext objects when doing it manually.

If I do this :

```
services.AddScoped<>(_ => new TokenService(null , null, "secret");
```

it doesn't work with the dependency injection of the other services.

As a workaround, I have added the string with a method in Program.cs but would like to remove this.

Comment: Not able to write a proper answer right now, but I have a vague memory that you can tell DI how to construct something... this, or something like it: `services.addSingleton<TokenService>(_ => new TokenService(null, null, "hello"));`

Comment: I had to change from Singleton to Scoped to use the UserManager and this code you gave me compiles but the UserManager is null when i try to use the service.

Comment: Ah yeah, because you're explicitly constructing it with null now. The accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally when you want to provide parameters to something that also needs to get dependencies injected you end up creating a factory. However in this case since the parameters are known during registration you can easily fix this registering a factory method directly:

```
services.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => new TokenService(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(), serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>(), "hello"));
```

In you comments you state that this can't be a singleton, that doesn't matter with the factory method, just as easy to register a transient for example:

```
services.AddTransient(serviceProvider => new TokenService(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>() , serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>(), "hello"));
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: yes that works, at first I wondered what was wrong but it should read this:

services.AddTransient(serviceProvider => new TokenService(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>() , serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>(), "hello"));